# word/VBA: Unable to retrieve formatted text from table

Tags: vba

I am using below code to generate XML from tables of word file.

`Sub exprt()
Dim nofT, cnt, tag, btxt As Integer

Dim Rcnt As Long

Dim tit, pTyp, cValu As String

Dim dum  As Range

Set a = ActiveDocument.Tables

nofT = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

Set docold = ActiveDocument`

For cnt = 5 To nofT
Selection.TypeText ("")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText ("")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Set dum = ActiveDocument.Tables(cnt).Cell(2, 1).Range
dum.End = dum.End - 1
tit = dum.Text
tit = LTrim(Right(tit, (Len(tit) - InStr(tit, ":"))))
Selection.TypeText (Chr(9) + "<" + Chr(33) + "[CDATA[" + tit + "]]><" + Chr(47) + "title_text_1>")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Rcnt = a(cnt).Rows.Count
Set dum = ActiveDocument.Tables(cnt).Cell(3, 1).Range
dum.End = dum.End - 1
pTyp = dum.Text
pTyp = LTrim(Right(pTyp, (Len(pTyp) - InStr(pTyp, ":"))))
tag = 1
For btxt = 6 To Rcnt - 1
Set dum = ActiveDocument.Tables(cnt).Cell(btxt, 1).Range.FormattedText
dum.End = dum.End - 1
Selection.TypeText (Chr(9) + "<" + Chr(33) + "[CDATA[" + dum + "]]><" + Chr(47) + "body_text_" + LTrim(Str(tag)) + ">")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
tag = tag + 1
Next
Set dum = docold.Tables(cnt).Cell(Rcnt, 1).Range
dum.End = dum.End - 1
Selection.TypeText (Chr(9) + "<" + Chr(33) + "[CDATA[" + dum + "]]><" + Chr(47) + "prompt_text_1>")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText ("<" + Chr(47) + "data>")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.Extend
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
newTxt = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection
Selection.Cut
Set dum = docold.Tables(cnt).Cell(1, 1).Range
dum.End = dum.End - 1
Call pub(dum.Text)
Next
End Sub

`Sub pub(nme As String)

Dim FolderPath As String

Dim FileName As String

FolderPath = "c:/Chandru/"

FileName = nme & ".xml"

Documents.Add

Selection.Paste

Call bld

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=FolderPath & FileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText

ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub`

Problem: I want to add "< b> & < /b >" for bold text, similarly for italic text. When i retrieve the table cell content, i am not getting formatted text. How do i can add < b> & < i> for bold & italic text respectively??

Answer (score 3):

In general I am not too sure if it is a really good idea to generate an XML file in that way, especially adding formats to your data. But that was not your question.

To extract the formatted text you rely on the

```
FormattedText
```

from a Range-object. Now you can use the resultinc Range-object to e.g. paste the formatted text somewhere else in your document. But it does not directly 'give' you the formattings to use in your code.

What you would have to do is to either parse this FormattedText-range object character (with formatting) for character or use another method (see below).

Example, output every character in the current selection with some formattings

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myChar As Variant

Set myRange = Selection.FormattedText

For Each myChar In myRange.Characters
    Debug.Print myChar.Text, myChar.Bold, myChar.Italic, myChar.Underline
Next
```

You could create a function parsing your range into a string that includes the formattings in HTML-format (i.e. bold as **...** and so on).

Doable bit tricky, because you need to make sure you that you don't create something that is not valid like

```
<b>bold <i>bold italic</b> just italic </i> (no good!)
```

(Word or most browsers might not care, but it is certanly no longer valid XML).

You might consider some other way to extract your formated table-content. Since from Word 2003 onwards you can save your documents in XML-format you could try to extract your data there. Word does keep track of open formatting-tags, but as always with Word, you hve a lot garbage.

```
... [extract from an XML-Export; use e.g. Notepad++ to get a pretty-print version]
  <w:body>
    <wx:sect>
      <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
          <w:tblStyle w:val="Tabellengitternetz"/>
          <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
          <w:tblLook w:val="01E0"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
          <w:gridCol w:w="9286"/>
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr wsp:rsidR="007A0EF3" wsp:rsidTr="007A0EF3">
          <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
              <w:tcW w:w="9286" w:type="dxa"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p wsp:rsidR="007A0EF3" wsp:rsidRDefault="007A0EF3" wsp:rsidP="007A0EF3">
              <w:r>
                <w:t>Titel </w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
              <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="007A0EF3">
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:b/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Bold</w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
              <w:r>
                <w:t/>
              </w:r>
              <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
              <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="007A0EF3">
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:i/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Italic</w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
              <w:r>
                <w:t/>
              </w:r>
              <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
              <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="007A0EF3">
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:b/>
                  <w:i/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>BoldItalic</w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
            </w:p>
          </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
...
```

Digging through the unimportant bits you find your text-body, your table(s), your text and corresponding formattings.

But as with most questions like this it all comes down to *how often* you need to run this task (how much effort you want to put into programming an automated solution), how much data is read and so on.

HTH
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the character formatting of each character in the Range individually.